# Access a IIS site on a remote machine on the same network using Host name instead of IP address and port number

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, web-deployment

I am hosting a .net core 3.0 app on IIS. Currently I have access to this using a remote machine on the network via my machine's IP address:port number(eg: 192.168.1.890:81).I can add a host name in the hosts file of my computer so that i can access it via that name (eg: www.xeroimport.com). But this is only for my own computer, I want to access it using the provided host name on all local computers in the same network. Also, I don't want to deploy my app to azure as it asks for credit card information so are there any alternatives ?

Comment: "any alternatives"? Talk to your local network administrators and ask them to configure the DNS server properly. It has nothing to do with programming now.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you should set up a DNS server in your local network as Lex says.

A DNS server is a computer server that contains a database of public IP addresses and their associated hostnames, and in most cases serves to resolve, or translate, those names to IP addresses as requested.

More details about how to set up a DNS server and configure a DNS server , you could refer to below article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/814591/how-to-install-and-configure-dns-server-in-windows-server-2003